# PHP DateTime constructor - date string format based on DateTimeZone

Tags: php, datetime

I have a multi national system that uses two different types of date formats. One uses "d-m-Y" the other uses "m-d-Y". I have a Local class that is responsible for creating a DateTime object based on a date string passed into it.

The string being passed in is dynamic and can be either version. The problem is that even if you specify the DateTimeZone in the DateTime constructor you still have to pass in a string based on 'm-d-y'.

I need to be able to pass a string to the DateTime constructor based on the DateTimeZone that is passed in along with it. For example, if my TimeZone is set to Australia/Sydney
the DateTime constructor should accept a string like '31/11/2017' but it doesn't. The DateTime constructor doesn't take into account the TimeZone passed in with the string. I would have to use DateTime::createFromFormat, but this means I would have to manually specify a format for hundreds of time zones. It would be much easier if the DateTime constructor would take a string format based on the time zone passed in like this...

`$dateTime = new DateTime('31/11/2017', new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney'))`

This should work but doesn't in my case. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? There must be a way to achieve this.

Comment: Use timestamp format instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the format for your date isn't accepted by PHP's DateTime constructor. For a workaround try this:

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '31/11/2017')
    ->setTimeZone('Australia/Sydney');
```

or

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '31/11/2017', 'Australia/Sydney');
```

Comment: When I try this my $dateTime variable is set as false.

I aslo tried this but it comes back as false as well...

DateTime::createFromFormat('31/11/2017','DD/MM/YYYY');

Comment: What's your PHP version?

Comment: We are using PHP 5.6

Comment: Updated my answer. Confused javascript date formats with PHP's formats. And fixed the orders of the parameters. Now they work.

Comment: Yes, this worked 

DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '29/11/2017', $this->getClinicTimezone());

I think the issues was that I needed to use 'd/m/Y'. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, but I thought that you were looking for a solution for getting the format for a specified time zone..

Comment: Yes you are right. This doesn't actually solve my problem. I jumped the gun. If I use this approach I would need to specify the format for every single timezone. I deally the formate would know what to use based on the timezone I pass in.

Comment: Do you need this for displaying or saving to database?

Comment: I need this for saving to a database. I did some looking around in our system and it looks like someone has already run into this issue before and tried to solve it. I was hoping there was a better approach but this will have to do. They have already mapped each Local/TimeZone to the date format. I just have to utilize it. It's not very extendable but looks to be my only solution. Using the createFromFormat method you mentioned I should be able to do this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: For saving into the database, you should really consider using the database provider's datetime column type format, or a timestamp. Don't save formatted datetime into the database, because when you need to order/index those columns, you won't be able to do that because of the different formats. The only place that dates should be used with format should be the user interface.

Comment: I misunderstood... We are using mySQL date columns. This method is converting the date coming from our frontend "datepicker" so we can save it to the database in the correct format.

Comment: then you can use a javascript solution onform submit: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Answer (score 1):

you can use the php-intl-extension to get default strings per locale-string

```
foreach (["en_US", "en_IE", "de_DE"] as $fmt) {
    $formatter = datefmt_create($fmt, IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
    echo datefmt_get_pattern($formatter) . "\n";
}
```

see the documentation on [datefmt_get_pattern](http://php.net/manual/intldateformatter.getpattern.php) for more details.

Comment: The "full" patterns returned by `datefmt_get_pattern()` still need conversion to PHP's format codes (e.g. `yyyy` to `Y`), but a good approach